# Why $\exp(x) = 1 + x + \Theta(x^2 )$?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

From a lecture:

> As $x \to 0$ (either positive or negative), we have $\exp(x) = 1 + x + \Theta(x^2)$.

Why is there equality and how should I understand that?

Comment: Do you know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem ?

Comment: @MartinR: To some extent, but only as approximation, not equality (but maybe that just the big-O notation that's confusing me). Thanks, I'll have a look!

Comment: $f(x)=g(x)+O(x^n) \Leftrightarrow \left|\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^n}\right|=A<\infty$, so you need to find the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\exp x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}<\infty$